# How does the gcc option -fstack-check exactly work?

Tags: gcc, stack

My program crashed when I added the option -fstack-check and -fstack-protector. __stack_chk_fail is called in the back trace.

So how could I know where the problem is ? What does -fstack-check really check ? 
The information about gcc seems too huge to find out the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After checked the assembly program. 
I think -fstack-check,  will add code write 0 to an offset of the stack pointer,  so to test if the program visit a violation address,  the program went crash if it does. 
e.g. mov   $0x0,-0x928(%esp)

Comment: can you elaborate with some code examples and output?

Comment: This has nothing to do with your error. See my answer below

Answer (score 3):

"`-fstack-protector' emits extra code to check for buffer overflows, such as stack
smashing attacks. This is done by adding a guard variable to
functions with vulnerable objects. This includes functions that
call alloca, and functions with buffers larger than 8 bytes. The
guards are initialized when a function is entered and then checked
when the function exits. If a guard check fails, an error message
is printed and the program exits"

[GCC Options That Control Optimization](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)

[GCC extension for protecting applications from stack-smashing attacks](http://archive.li/BnU1V)

[Smashing The Stack For Fun And Profit](http://insecure.org/stf/smashstack.html)

I Hope this will give some clue..

Comment: Please note that `-fstack-protector` and `-fstack-check` are different options. (for fellow googlers)

Answer (score 3):

`-fstack-check`: If two feature macros `STACK_CHECK_BUILTIN` and `STACK_CHECK_STATIC_BUILTIN` are left at the default 0, it just inserts a NULL byte every 4kb (page) when the stack grows. 
By default only one, but when the stack can grow more than one page, which is the most dangerous  case, every 4KB. linux >2.6 only has only one small page gap between the stack and the heap, which can lead to stack-gap attacks, known since 2005. 
See [What exception is raised in C by GCC -fstack-check option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26370839/what-exception-is-raised-in-c-by-gcc-fstack-check-option) for assembly.
It is enabled in gcc at least since 2.95.3, in clang since 3.6.

`__stack_chk_fail` is the inserted `-fstack-protector` code which verifies an inserted stack canary value which might be overwritten by a simple stack overflow, e.g. by recursion.