# Can I use -fstack-check when compiling my Ubuntu 10.04 kernel module?

Tags: gcc, linux-kernel, stack, stack-overflow, ubuntu-10.04

It looks like my kernel module is performing some stack smashing under heavy loads. Can I use the -fstack-check compile option for kernel modules? It appears as if that compile option causes the compiler to emit additional code, but not link to a library or runtime. Is that correct?

I have a very simplified kernel that does not do much. I can load that simple kernel with and without slub debugging enabled, and it will also load with and without -fstack-check at compile. When I start testing my module, it starts crashing when I use the -fstack-check compile option, whereas it seems to not trip errors with just slub debugging.

A different question ([How does the gcc option -fstack-check exactly work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369886/how-does-the-gcc-option-fstack-check-exactly-work)) provided some information but I haven't been able to find examples of people using the -fstack-check option in kernel module compilations.

Answer (score 0):

The stack space inside the Linux kernel is *severely* limited. Go over your code with a fine comb to check there are no paths using too much in local variables, no `alloca()` allowed *at all*. Other than that, the kernel environment is harsh. Check your logic carefully. Add tests for possibly out of range data, trace data to wherever it comes from and make sure it is always as you believe. Data from userland is *always* a reason for extra paranoia.